# Django - ManyToMany where I could select the same foreign model multiple times

Tags: django, database, orm, many-to-many

Apologies if this has been answered, I'm uncertain how to word it so couldn't find an existing solution.

Let's say I have a basic ManyToMany relationship as shown here:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()

class Pizza(models.Model):
    toppings = models.ManyToMany(Topping)
```

That's simple and great, however in the project I'm working on, I want to be able to select the same Topping more than once.  For example, ["pepperoni", "mushroom", "onion"] would be a perfectly good result, but I need to allow something like ["pepperoni", "pepperoni", "pepperoni"]

I've tried using a intermediate class, where Pizza has a ManyToMany to Topping, which is just a foreignkey to ToppingType, which is the Charfield -

```
class ToppingType(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()

class Topping(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(ToppingType)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    toppings = models.ManyToMany(Topping)
```

and that works, however it means if one day I create something with five "pepperoni" selections, I then permanently have five copies of pepperoni as a Topping in my database.

As I mentioned at the top, I'm sure there's a fairly clean solution, but I've had trouble figuring out how to phrase my searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `ManyToManyField` to the `Topping`, you can let the `Topping` act as a [*junction table* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) and thus specify this as [**`through=…`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through):

```
class ToppingType(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    toppings = models.ManyToMany(
        ToppingType,
        through='Topping'
    )

class Topping(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(ToppingType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here you thus create a `Topping` object per `pizza` per topping. But you do not duplicate the `ToppingType`s. In fact if you do not specify a `through=…`, then Django creates a (hidden) model that acts as the junction model.

You thus can create for example as `ToppingType`s pepperoni and onion:

```
pepperoni = ToppingType.objects.create(name='pepperoni')
onion = ToppingType.objects.create(name='onion')
```

and then for a pizza add `pepperoni`, `onion`, and `pepperoni`:

```
my_pizza = Pizza.objects.create()
Topping.objects.create(pizza=my_pizza, type=pepperoni)
Topping.objects.create(pizza=my_pizza, type=onion)
Topping.objects.create(pizza=my_pizza, type=pepperoni)
```

Comment: That looks like exactly my solution, thanks!  As soon as I can apply it to the real code I'll confirm and click appropriate buttons

Comment: Finally got to try it, and it took me a minute to readjust to creating the objects using the "through" model, but it seems to be working perfectly.  

Note:  Django Admin seems to have no idea what to make of this relationship, so unless there's a workaround, it's worth noting that you lose that particular convenience.  Thanks again!